# The use of global variable does not work

Tags: php, magento, global-variables, global

This is the global variable for the class and the function which always gets called first

```
private $product_sku;

public function indexAction(){
  $request = $this->_getValidRequest();
  global $product_sku;

  if ($this->flag == FALSE) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $product_sku);
        $product_sku = $request['sku'];
    }
    else {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('printed_order_number', $request['pon']);
        $product_sku = $product->getSku();
    }

    // here I call the other function
}
```

And the other function that uses the global variable

```
public function showPopUpInProductViewPageAction(){
    $request = $this->_getValidRequest();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $GLOBALS['product_sku']);

    Mage::log($GLOBALS['product_sku']); // logging $product_sku to check its value, but it's empty
}
```

*These are no the complete functions, but just the relevant code to the problem*

So, in the second function the `$product` object is empty, because `product_sku` has no value.

I don't want to repeat the code of checking for the `flag`.

How can I make use of it like in Java, i.e. - I declare the variable in the beginning of the class, I assign a value to it *(only once)* in the first function and then I use this value wherever I want in the class.

Comment: Just because you access something through `$this` doesn't make it `global`.... in fact accessing it through `$this` makes it an instance variable or property.... which is definitely __not__ global

Comment: @MarkBaker - I updated my question with some new approach that I tried (from what I found here http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php ) but that didn't help either...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using PHP Globals you need to use Magento’s Registry Pattern. You can find the detail of the Magento registry pattern here
http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

as @Mark Baker said, $product_sku is not a gobal variable in your scenario.

If you want the value of the variable $product_sku to persit, you can declare the variable as static as mentioned below:

//Declaring the static property in class

public static $product_sku = 0;

//Accessing the static property

self::$product_sku;

Please go through the static keyword in detail at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Hope it will help you.

Comment: but I don't want it to be static. I want to assign a value to it in the first function (only once for the whole process) and then use that value everywhere in the class, that I want.

Comment: you can re-assign a value to it like self::$product_sku = $request['sku']; in first function